# gmail like account verification with phone call

Tags: php

google recently(not very recently) started to verify new gmail accounts bt phone. when account is created and you are on the final step, a robot calls by phone and tell you the verification number. PHP-Side is OK but the calling section i have no idea. how can i do that? where to start?

Comment: First, one must create the universe...

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be providing the user an input field for their phone number.